# Проблема с контейнерами в Debian

Tags: debian, lxc

У меня на сервере есть 2 контейнера lxc. На обеих стоит debian. Для 2х свои ip. Один работает нормально, а на втором (я его только создал) не работает сеть. Я не имел опыта с 2-мя контейнерами, поэтому прошу помощи.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
#auto  eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#address   213.239.197.111
#netmask   255.255.255.224
#gateway   213.239.197.97
# default route to access subnet
#up route add -net 213.239.197.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 213.239.197.97 eth0

auto br0 
  iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_fd 0 
  address 213.239.197.111
  broadcast 213.239.197.127
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 213.239.197.97

# Создаем bridge br1

auto br1  
    iface br1 inet static   
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 0
    address 78.47.26.77
    broadcast 78.47.26.79
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway 78.47.26.73

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:4f8:130:622e::2
netmask 64
gateway fe80::1
```

Конфиг первого, с которым все ок

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags        = up
lxc.network.name         = eth1
lxc.network.link         = br0
lxc.network.veth.pair    = veth-01
lxc.network.ipv4         = 213.239.197.122/28
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 213.239.197.97
lxc.network.hwaddr       = 00:50:56:00:9C:81
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/only/rootfs

# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf

# Container specific configuration
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/only/fstab
lxc.utsname = only
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

Конфиг второго, с которым проблемы

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags        = up
lxc.network.name         = eth2
lxc.network.link         = br1
lxc.network.veth.pair    = veth-01
lxc.network.ipv4         = 78.47.26.77/28
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 78.47.26.73
lxc.network.hwaddr       = 00:50:56:00:3A:65
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/bolide/rootfs
# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf

# Container specific configuration
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/bolide/fstab
lxc.utsname = bolide
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

Comment: Почему у вас у моста и у контейнера идентичные ip?

Comment: где они одинаковые?

Comment: lxc.network.ipv4 второго контейнера объявлен 78.47.26.77 и принадлежащим мосту br1. На хостсистеме br1 указан address тоже 78.47.26.77.